# Unable to whitelist the IP of a client on Azure to connect to Azure SQL Server

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-virtual-network

Using Azure SQL Server. We have a client from another subscription on the same tenant trying to access SQL Server via username and password (connection string). In case it matters, the client is residing on an Azure Windows VM.

We have tried whitelisting, in the Firewall rules, external and internal IPs related to the client, to no avail. We tried adding "Allow Azure Services and resources to access this server", that worked, but it is too wide of a scope.

We have connected the client to an Azure Web App that is deployed to the same Azure resource group to try to extract the client IP, to check if it is not whitelisted, but he IP is already whitelisted.

We wanted to try the brute force approach of trying to whitelist a range from 0.0.0.0 to 255.255.255.255 to try to zoom in on the IP that the client is using, but that is proven difficult to implement.

- Is there a way to discover the rejected IP addresses by SQL Server firewall in a log
- Is there any other way to discover what IP the client is using to connect
- Managed Identity is not an option
- Any other suggestion to investigate?

Answer (score 0):

Allow Azure Services and resources to access this server will only work for "trusted Azure Services" - I know this term is a bit confusing. But it does not cover Azure VMs, App Service etc. as the workload there is no trustful.

When connecting from you Azure VM, you need to understand how the egress traffic leaves the vnet: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/ip-services/default-outbound-access

An easier and more secure way would be to use [Service Endpoints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-network-service-endpoints-overview) or even better [private endpoints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/private-link/private-endpoint-overview). As those enable the subnet to access the Database instead of an IP.

You can check with any IP resolver what your actual IP is? e.g. https://wtfismyip.com/

For App Services you could also use Service Endpoints or Private Endpoints, but that will require [VNET Integration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-vnet-integration) or a App Service Environment.